# WebUSB disconnects on Android after a while

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

I have implemented the web USB API for the USB-to-TTL chip CH340. It works pretty good on the PC but when I connect my phone to the chip (using direct cable and/or OTG cable) the API will disconnect after a minute or two. This doesn't happen if I use a Serial Terminal App on the same phone. Same will happen on multiple Chromium based browsers.

And as soon as I physically disconnect the chip from the phone it will freeze and restart the phone.

Here's my beta test site: https://grovkillen.com/webusb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior shouldn't happen (especially the freezing and crashing part) and is likely a Chromium or Android bug. Please open an issue on crbug.com and include any crash IDs from chrome://crashes in the report. Reply here with the bug link so I'm sure to see it.

Comment: Yep, I will make a debug log and then open an issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One question though... How should I debug it? I got the CH340 connected to the phone's usb-c port, and debugging the phone is supposed to be through that same port. The freeze + crash = reboot only occurs if I disconnect the device.

Comment: chrome://crashes didn't contain any crash info other than some which occurred 8-10 months ago.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1170734

Comment: crash/bb80c954d72cce65 I did get a crash report now